# Image not displayed in asp.net email signature

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, signature

I am creating an asp.net app that sends out an email. I need to attach an corporate logo in the signature. My image is displayed as

[image].

My code is:

```
LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(
                          "c:\\Data\\Misc\\Images\\CorpLogo.jpg", "image/jpeg");
logo.ContentId = "corpLogo";
logo.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body>" + msgBody + "<br><img src=cid:corpLogo/><br></body></html>", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
message.AlternateViews.Add(av1);

message.Body = msgBody;
```

When I hover over "logo" I can see the "contentlink" value is null.
Why would the image not be displayed?

Comment: The image won't be displayed anywhere apart from your dev machine, as it looks like you are referring to a local image, it needs to be hosted somewhere public so its accessible. A look at the HTML in the email will also help answering your question.

Comment: The reference to my local machine is just for testing. That will change once this is in production

Comment: a look at the HTML in the email then... or are you trying to attach the image?

Comment: I don't understand. What about the html?

Comment: In outlook for example you can view the source of an email.

Comment: The email view source shows: <br><img src=cid:corpLogo/><br></body></html>

Comment: Have you added the linked resource to the AlternateView htmlview. Like htmlview.resources.add(logo) .

Comment: Yes, just updated my original post

Comment: If you're going to host the image eventually, why not just do this via the usual `img src=...` method?

Comment: @ashes999 I think he wants to send the image as an attachment.

Comment: @geepie Not as attachment. As a signature

Comment: @greepie I think you're right.

Comment: Yee but I think the linkedresource class will add the image as an attachment regardless of where its used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update

If you still haven't sorted it, put a break on the linked resource line and check the path of the image, you might need to use server.mappath

---

Check here, i think this is what you are trying to do.

http://log.itto.be/?p=486

Here is a full example. Try simplify your code down to the minimum to get it working.

http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/2.6.aspx

Comment: Have you hovered over the linked resource object when debugging and checked the path is correct?

Comment: There is no path when I hover over the LinkedResource object.

Answer (score 0):

Attatch the image to the email and then you can show it on every client, not just on your PC where C:\something has it.